# How to Speed up PHP Mail ? (using CRON)

Tags: php, email, cron

I'm using PHP 5 and creating Mail commands to send information.

My Linux (Shared) Host (www.KoreDomains.com) is sending the E-mails approximately on an hourly basis.

What would be a good CRON command / set of commands to speed up the process (say E-mail what is in the queue every 5 minutes) ?

The goal is to make it so the E-mails show up to the user in near "Real-Time".

Thanks, in advance, for your help !

James

Comment: This is not really a question in it's current state. You have posted your solution without actually attempting it yourself. At a basic level you'd need to write a queue system for processing the emails - first in first out style.

Comment: What kind of mail server are you accessing? PHP itself doesn't deliver mail to end recipients. It just takes whatever you pass into the `mail()` function and gives it to an external SMTP server. It's up to that server to actually deliver the email, and on a shared host, it's unlikely you can do anything to speed up its queue processing.

Comment: Brief and quick suggestions would be 1) Speak with your Host and see if they can adjust any settings on their end to expedite your email sending (they may also have throttling limits, etc. which could cause problems in the future, if you are email-focused), 2) Look at handling your Email through a separate SMTP server (even through GMail) if #1 gets you no joy. [There are tutorials on #2 around the net - just Google a bit.]

Answer (score 0):

As with every issue related to sending mail from php I've ever come across, this is nothing to do with PHP and all about the configuration of the MTA. It doesn't matter what you do in terms of scheduling when you send mail nor how you tweak the PHP code since it appears that the MTA only processes the queue every hour.

If you want mail to be sent as soon as possible, then you need to change the MTA settings. That's not going to be practical on most managed services, let alone a shared one. You'll need to find a different provider. But don't expect providers to publish information about the specifics of how the MTA is configured.

Or keep your code where it is and try connecting to a different MTA (you'll need a SMTP capable PHP client - e.g. phpmailer) and this presupposes that your service provider has configured the server to allow outgoing SMTP connections and can resolve IP addresses.